# Display minutes and seconds total in Javascript Timer

Tags: javascript, timer

Everything I have so far is working great, although I'd like an alert that will display the amount of time used on the timer.

Example, starting timer at **00:10** and stopping at **-00:20**, the message alert should say **30 seconds**

My problem is `stopTimer()` which is the STOP button, on click it should display the amount of seconds, minutes however I'm having trouble with.

How can I form minutes in there as well, if the client went that long? [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ttphow9/2/)

```
    var totseconds = 10;
    var seconds = totseconds;

    function floor(x) {
        return x | 0;
    }

    function pad(n) {
        if (n < 0) {
            n = -n;
        }
        if (n < 10) {
            return '0' + n.toString();
        }
        return n.toString();
    }


    function stopTimer() {
        clearTimeout(countdownTimer);

        if (seconds > 60) {
            var rs = seconds % 60;
            var m = seconds / 60;
            windows.alert((totalseconds / 60) - (m + 1) + " minutes and " + totalseconds - (rs + 1) + " seconds")
        }
        //else {window.alert((seconds +1)+ " seconds");}
        else {
            window.alert(totseconds - (seconds + 1) + " seconds");
        }
    }

    function secondPassed() {
        var minutes = pad(floor(seconds / 60));
        if (seconds < 0) {
            minutes = '-' + minutes;
        }
        var remainingSeconds = pad(seconds % 60);

        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;

        if (seconds > 0) {
            seconds--;
            if (seconds > 8) {
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            } else if (seconds == 5) {
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            }
        } else {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            if (seconds % 2 == 0) {
                document.getElementById('skull').style.display = "block";
            }

            if (seconds % 2 != 0) {
                document.getElementById('skull').style.display = "none";
            }
            seconds--;
        }
    }
<img id="skull" src="http://s15.postimg.org/es5w3xpob/skull.gif" style="position:absolute;  z-index: -1;display:none;">
<div style=" z-index:10;">
    <p align="center"> <span id="countdown" style="color:black; font-size: 50px; font-weight: bold;"></span>

        </br>
        <button onclick="countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000)">Start</button>
        <button onclick="stopTimer()">Stop</button>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Use some math? What's the specific issue?

Comment: The variables that I have setup are quite noice, thats why I dont want to screw many things up. I attempted the math in stopTimer() but I'm not sure why its not working.

Comment: The tricky part is negative values.

Comment: Not really; math work with negative numbers as well, and some time with a paper and pencil should be enough to get you started--just look at possible values, figure out what the right answer is, then figure out how to get from paper to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confusion caused by counting seconds backwards seems to be the problem. On the fiddle in `function stopTimer()` changing

```
    if (seconds > 60) { // .... more than a minute
```

to

```
    if(seconds < -60) { // ... more than a minute
```

causes code for over a minute to get executed (which as written has errors and will need debugging). To clarify the logic and make coding easier when counting backwards may I suggest calculating something like

```
   var elapsedSeconds = - (seconds - totseconds);
```

Comment: var elapsedSeconds = - (seconds - totseconds); was an amazing fix, thanks man.